# NSObjectFromString... Any way to do it?

Tags: objective-c, string, object, runtime

So Objective-C has these nice functions `NSClassFromString()` and `NSProtocolFromString()`, which return a class or protocol from a passed string name.  Is there any way to do this with an object?

Comment: You could store it as an 'id' .. heh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because objects don't have canonical names or string representations. With a class, there either is a class called "NSWindow" or there isn't. With objects, that correspondence doesn't really apply. If you're looking to serialize an object, check out the [NSCoding protocol](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and accompanying [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i).

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of is `-description`, but I suspect you're looking more for introspection into all the members than the basic description. If you are, you're going with [Chuck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114479/nsobjectfromstring-any-way-to-do-it/2114492#2114492), because you need to serialize/deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to instantiate an Object, you could also do this

```
Class class = NSClassFromString(className);
id object = [class new];
```